# How to supress authentication window when using URLConnection in Eclipse Plugin code

Tags: eclipse, authentication, eclipse-plugin, urlconnection

I have created an Eclipse Plugin, and within that I have created a Wizard by extending org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard. In that I am using java.net.URLConnection to perform Basic Authentication with a server, like so:

```
String auth = new String(Base64.encodeBase64((username + ":" + password).getBytes()));
log(auth);

URL url = new URL(server);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

// this fails -- can't stop the auth window when the username/password are invalid
conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);

monitor.beginTask("Authenticating: ", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
```

If the username & password are valid, then everything works fine. But if the username & password do not authenticate, Eclipse pops up its own "Password Required" window (which I don't want -- I want to manage the failed authentication myself). I would have thought that URLConnection.setAllowUserInteraction would stop this, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

See extension point [org.eclipse.equinox.security.loginModule](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_equinox_security_loginModule.html).